# dojo eventListener via dojo.connect attach to multiple objects with same id

Tags: event-handling, dojo, mouseevent, dom-events

I am trying to attach an onclick event to a set of links with the same `id("linkToDisplay")` and it doesn't seem to be triggering my onclick event code is as follows:

```
var handle = [];
var link = dojo.query('#linkToDisplay a').forEach(function(node, index, array){

    handle.push(dojo.connect(node,
        "onclick",
        null,
        function(evt) {
            console.log("mouseup detected, firring off server request");
            dojo.xhrGet({url:'default/data/getPageContent?main=true&pageId='+evt.target.name,
                         load: funcCallBack,
                         error: funcError});
            }
          ));

    });
```

funcError and funcCallBack are defined and working (if I only pass in a single object retrieved by dojo.getId, but otherwise my script fails silently).

I am putting this code inside the dojo.addOnLoad code block, and I don't see any events fired off when I click anywhere on the page so I'm pretty sure its not a problem with attaching the event listener to the wrong piece of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it appears that dojo enforces a schema where id's are unique, so if some DOM element has an id that matches another the end result is that the query method only returns the first.

here is a sample of what I ended up with:

```
dojo.query(".links a").onclick(function(evt){
                                    dojo.stopEvent(evt);
                                    var link = evt.target;
                                    onSubmit(link)
                                }
                        );
```

.links specifies the class="links", and then from there I sort for any anchor objects by including the 'a' after and I use a convenience function for the onclick event, grab the target and pass it to the onSubmit function (which contains some validation and an xhr request.).

Comment: For what it's worth, it's considered invalid markup to use an ID on any DOM nodes more than once. Browser behavior can be inconsistent at that point. The solution you've came up with is really the best one. If you need to specify a group of elements, a class is going to be the best bet. An ID is meant for one distinct and unique node.

Comment: @Brian - yeah after reading some more I am find that it is best to leave id's as unique, originally I had thought that a good abstraction for applying css styling would be to use class for parent nodes, or nodes that had unspecified children and id's for the specified...it was a good starting point but a habit I am dropping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var k=dojo.byId("linkToDisplay");
dojo.connect(k,'onclick',this,'yourfunction')
```